# Insert word document into SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, pdf

I have a question: can I load `.docx` files into a column `documentbody` with a datatype of `ntext` into my table `testing.dbo.table00` using a SQL query?

I'm getting an error message

> Msg 206, Level 16, State 2, Line 2
>   Operand type clash: varbinary(max) is incompatible with ntext

Code:

```
INSERT INTO [Testing].[dbo].[table00](documentbody) 
    SELECT BulkColumn
    FROM OPENROWSET(BULK N'C:\Users\XXX\filename.docx', SINGLE_BLOB) as TheFile
```

I have also tried the following query:

```
INSERT INTO [Testing].[dbo].[table00](documentbody) 
    SELECT BulkColumn
    FROM OPENROWSET(BULK N'C:\Users\XXX\filename.docx', CLOB) as TheFile
```

But I'm getting this error:

> Msg 155, Level 15, State 1, Line 4
>   'CLOB' is not a recognized BULK OPENROWSET provider option.

How can I solve the error? Thanks

Comment: `ntext`, `text`, and `image` data types will be removed in a future version of SQL Server. Avoid using these data types in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use them. Use `nvarchar(max)`, `varchar(max)`, and `varbinary(max)` instead. [See details here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx). Plus: storing a Word file results in a **binary** stream of bytes - use `varbinary` - not a textual `varchar(max)` column .....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It says in the error - you are trying to insert `varbinary` data into a column that is `ntext` data type. You should change column `documentbody` to a `varbinary` data type. You can do this using the syntax:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name
ALTER COLUMN column_name datatype;
```

Further reading - [binary and varbinary (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/ms188362.aspx)

Comment: Thanks! managed to load it in after changing the column into a varbinary data type.